# Image not found or type unknown dompdf laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

[view in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA8AV.png)

I tried to fix this problem in a few days but could not find a solution. my picture doesn't show in the pdf. Help me please.this is code in controller.
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3hfF.png)
and this code in view
[in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9vuG.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Nurul Hidayah try the following

```
//run the following command in terminal 
php artisan storage:link

// set your storage path in side .env
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public

//access you file inside blade file 
asset('storage/report/qm'.$r->qm)
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestions, but still not solving my problem, i still get error message "Image not found or type unknown" :(

Comment: I have set the options like : (-- setOptions([
            'tempDir' => public_path(),
            'chroot'  => public_path('report/qm')
         ]) . --) and isworked for me, thanks